After using belenaEtcher my USB stick was not accesseble anymore. I think I can throw it away
After using belenaEtcher my USB stick was not accesseble anymore. I think I can throw it away. USB stick is write protected and can't format the USB stick, it says.

balenaEtcher uses the dd command in its back-end. The linked duplicate question is specific to a USB flash drive that has lost most of its capacity after using the dd command on it.

There is probably only a problem with the partition table and/or the file system, but there might also be a hardware problem. You can analyze the problem according to this link and if you are lucky, find a solution.

I tried the suggestions above but it didn't help. After using rufus.ie problem was solved.
